# PHP force File downloads without applying headers

Tags: php

Is there a way to force any given file specified without giving the headers for it? What I have is a handful of different docs and other file types that a client wishes to offer up as download upon request, however they want to obscure the file path best they can. Unfortunately I don't know what file types most of these are and they want a somewhat dynamic ability. I'm not getting paid for this piece. So I am looking for quick and dirty if at all possible. Something that doesnt force me to come up with a logic for every file type possible just so I can have the headers built right for the file type in question so it downloads proper..

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Your requirements are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I think this can be done with .htaccess. Not completely sure what you're asking though.

Comment: I guess generally what I want to do is have one file lets call it downloads.php, then any file I pull data about from a DB (mostly the file path on the server) be it txt, doc, pdf, jpg, whatever anything and everything goes as far as file types. What I need is something that will trigger a download of the file regardless of the file type even if its something the browser would open within the viewing pane by default.

Comment: only way i know how to do it currently is by specifying specific headers for the file type to prompt the download. Though I could be a bit wrong about that. Anyway its all about forcing what ever file path I give the script to download. from a local file on the server

Comment: I don't fully understand your problem. So you want to call something like downloads.php?file=myfile.doc and have the browser open a download/save-to-folder dialog instead of opening directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, if I undertand your problem, you want an easy way to download any type of file using a php script.

First of, you have a couple of ways to do it...

The most insecure one: 
- You have a directory (lets say 'files/') where all files are stored. You create a script that receive a param (filename) and you look for the file in that directory. This is insecure because anyone can try to download any file there is, and also access subdirectories just passing "../" as param. You must need to do some parse there.

Other option is to use a DB, you store the filenames and associates them to an unique ID, later you have you script like: download.php?id=1 and it downloads the file which DB id is 1. This is the best I think.

Anyway, you can choose whatever you think is best, the code to force a download dialog should be something like:

```
$file = "my_file.zip"; // this is what you will get from a param (i.e. ?file=my_file.zip) or from DB query
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file"); // this is totally needed
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
```

That should do the trick.

Good luck!